# Map few docs with NextJs and Firebase

Tags: firebase, next.js, firebase-storage

hope you have an amazing day!
i'm new with NextJs and i have a problem when i have to map my Firebase documents, i need to put 5 cards in my web, but i setting all the documents that i have.

this is my call ref

```
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {

    (async () => {
      const callref = collection(db, "posts", limit(3));
      const snapshots = await getDocs(callref);
      if (posts.length < 5) {
        const docs = snapshots.docs.map(doc => {
          const data = doc.data()
          data.id = doc.id
          return data
        });
        setPosts(docs);
        console.log(docs)
      } else {
        return;
      }
    })()

  }, [])
```

and this is the map code in my web

```
          {
            posts.map((post) => (
              <div className="contProduct">
                <div className="imageProduct">
                  <img src={post.image}></img>
                </div>
                <div className="descriptionProduct">
                  <h3>{post.title}</h3>
                  <p>{post.subtitle}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))
          }
```

i tried putting an if sentense but it shows me an error, i dont know how to show only five posts.

Thank you for your time and I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the question well, but maybe what you need is using  the firestore `limit()` function, just like this :

```
const callref = collection(db, "posts", limit(3));
callRef.limit(5);
const snapshots = await getDocs(callref);
```